# How do I suppress the output of multiple commands whose output each run infinitely?

Tags: linux

Let's say the I have two commands to run in Linux: cmd1, cmd2 and cmd3. cmd1 and cmd2 each give output in the console log that run forever unless if you manually execute it.

Normally, I would use multiple terminals, though I'm running them on a virtual machine that would have to run each in the background.

I tried running the following successfully:

```
# nohup cmd1 > /dev/null 2>&1&
[1] pid1
```

But if I run the next command:

```
# nohup cmd2 > /dev/null 2>&1&
[2] pid2
[1]   Exit 1                 nohup cmd1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The process is killed for cmd1. Then later for cmd2:

```
[2]+  Exit 1                 nohup cmd2 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Is there a way I can have two commands whose output can be redirected to /dev/null?

Perhaps a way to duplicate /dev/null and then have each command output suppressed to each /dev/null? The important part is that I can run cmd3 after cmd1 and cmd2.

Comment: Testing under `zsh`, I don't have the same issue you do. *Three* instances of `dd if=/dev/urandom > /dev/null 2>&1` are able to run simultaneously just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to run multiple commands using the same /dev/null concurrently.
Maybe your cmd1 and cmd2 programs have some dependencies that cannot tolerate each other. It would be better to check them again
I've tested in the bash shell

[See the attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln2FB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. Apparently these command processes terminated because of some missing configuration for cmd1 and cmd2; the absence of that configuration terminated both commands.

Tung Vs was correct. You can run multiple commands onto /dev/null concurrently.